# JAVA IceCreamProject couldn't run

Tags: java

This project couldn't run.Please help me.
http://pastebin.com/FX3JdUqb

`IceCreamFlavor printPurchasedIceCreams()`
this method is just return all ice creams in ArrayList, below is my code:

**IceCreamShopMain.java:**

```
public class IceCreamShopMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(IceCreamFlavor.HAZELNUT.getName());
        System.out.println("The price of ice-cream is " + IceCreamFlavor.HAZELNUT.getPrice() + " dollars.");
        Customer c = new Customer(IceCreamFlavor.WHIPPEDCREAM);
        c.setCustomerName("Amy");
        Customer c2 = new Customer(IceCreamFlavor.ALMOND, "Mawson");        
        System.out.println(c.getCustomerName() + "`s purchased items are " + c.printPurchasedIceCreams() + ".");
        c.buy(IceCreamFlavor.OREOCOOKIECRUMBLES);
        System.out.println(c.printPurchasedIceCreams());
        System.out.println(c.icecream.getName());
        System.out.println(c2.getCustomerName() + " bought " + c2.icecream.getName() + "-Ice"
                + " which was " + c2.icecream.getPrice() + " dollars.");
        Customer c3 = new Customer(IceCreamFlavor.OREOCOOKIECRUMBLES, "Mickey");
        c3.buy(IceCreamFlavor.ALMOND);
        c3.buy(IceCreamFlavor.WHIPPEDCREAM);
        System.out.println(c3.printPurchasedIceCreams());

    }
}
```

**Customer.java:**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Customer {
    public IceCreamFlavor icecream;
    public int price;
    private String customerName;
    static String hamper;

    List<IceCreamFlavor> purchasedIceCreams = new ArrayList<IceCreamFlavor>();


    Customer(IceCreamFlavor icecream) {
        this.icecream = icecream;
    }

    Customer(IceCreamFlavor icecream, String customerName) {
        this.icecream = icecream;
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

//  String getName() {
//      return icecream.getName();
//  }
//
//  int getPrice() {
//      return icecream.getPrice();
//  }

    String getCustomerName() {
        return this.customerName;
    }

    void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;

    }

    void buy(IceCreamFlavor icecream) {
        // not really sure what business do here
        // just return the Ice cream.
//      this.icecream = icecream;
        purchasedIceCreams.add(icecream);

    }

     IceCreamFlavor printPurchasedIceCreams() {
        // not really sure what business do here
        // just return the Ice cream.
        for(int i = 0; i < purchasedIceCreams.size(); i++) {
            purchasedIceCreams.get(i);



        return purchasedIceCreams.get(i);


        }
     }
}
```

**IceCreamFlavor.java:**

```
enum IceCreamFlavor {

    HAZELNUT("Hazelnut", 300), WHIPPEDCREAM("WhippedCream", 270), ALMOND("Almond",
            370), OREOCOOKIECRUMBLES("OreoCookieCrumbles", 500), MARSHMALLOWS("Marshmallows", 420);

    public String name;
    public int price;

    private IceCreamFlavor(String name, int price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

}
```

**Error Log:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:      This method must return a result of type IceCreamFlavor
>
> at Customer.printPurchasedIceCreams(Customer.java:45)   at
>   IceCreamShopMain.main(IceCreamShopMain.java:8) This method must return
>   a result of type   IceCreamFlavor

Comment: for example,System.out.println(c3.printPurchasedIceCreams()); this code want to return all ice creams stored in ArrayList which customer c3 bought

Comment: Didn't you ask this same or similar question earlier today? Wasn't that question closed for being low-quality?

Comment: The error is very clear, are you sure `return purchasedIceCreams.get(i);` is of the expected return type. Maybe you need to typecast it explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java always wants to be 100% sure that you return something in your not void functions. It can happen that `purchasedIceCreams.size() == 0` and in this case, the execution does not step into the for loop in `printPurchasedIceCreams()`, so it is not guaranteed that you return something, this is why you get the Unresolved compilation error:

```
IceCreamFlavor printPurchasedIceCreams() {
        for(int i = 0; i < purchasedIceCreams.size(); i++) {
            purchasedIceCreams.get(i);
            return purchasedIceCreams.get(i);
        }
}
```

You can quickly fix the problem by adding a `return null;` to the end of the function outside the for loop or re-structuring your function.

```
IceCreamFlavor printPurchasedIceCreams() {
            for(int i = 0; i < purchasedIceCreams.size(); i++) {
                return purchasedIceCreams.get(i);
            }
            return null;
}
```

[Here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-return-the-value-from-a-function-based-on-some-fulfillment-of-condition) I found a problem similar to yours, you might want to check it out to learn more.

Side note: This is unrelated to the error but it is bad practice that the name of your method does not match its functionality. You should have two separate methods: a `printPurchasedIceCreams()` method which does all the printing but does not return anything and a `getFirstPurchasedIceCream()` method which returns the first ice cream (or null).

Comment: Now I read your answer deeply and think a lot cuz your ansere is high-level.

Comment: Now, I will fix method names, wait a moment

Comment: I was creating getFirstPurchasedIceCream today. But it couldn't run. http://pastebin.com/dXg7LyLR

Answer (score -1):

is this also OK? Im full go feelings of gratefulness.

```
List<IceCreamFlavor> printPurchasedIceCreams() {
    // not really sure what business do here
    for (int i = 0; i < purchasedIceCreams.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(purchasedIceCreams.get(i));

    }

    return purchasedIceCreams;

}
```

Comment: Yes, if that is the business to do there. :)